# Find the closest time to a given 24-hour time

Tags: javascript, time

Given the function signature:

`getNearestToDesiredTime(left, middle, right, desiredTime)`

where:

- `left, middle, right` are possibly-valid 24-hour times (`1830, -1, 1900`)
- `desiredTime` is a desired 24-hour time (`1845`)

how would you find the time CLOSEST to the desired time?

In a situation where the time arguments are all equidistant to the desired time, the later time should be returned. (in the above example, `1900` should be returned, because `1900` and `1830` are both `15` minutes from the desired `1845`).

This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to quite work.

```
const timeDiffInMinutes = (t1, t2) => {
  const t1Mins = t1 / 100 * 60 + t1 % 100;
  const t2Mins = t2 / 100 * 60 + t2 % 100;
  return t2Mins - t1Mins;
};

const getNearestToDesiredTime = (left, middle, right, desiredTime) => {
  if (middle !== -1) {
    return middle;
  } else if (left === -1 && right === -1) {
    return null;
  }

  // result should be whatever time is _closest_ to the desiredTime.
  // if both options are equi-distant to the desired time, show the later time.
  const leftIsCloser =
    timeDiffInMinutes(desiredTime, left) <
    timeDiffInMinutes(desiredTime, right);

  return leftIsCloser ? left : right;
};
```

Test Cases:

```
// this should be 1900
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1830, 1900, 1945, 1900))

// this should be 1915
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1830, 1915, 1945, 1900))

// this should be 1830
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1830, -1, 1945, 1845))

// this should be 1945
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1830, -1, 1945, 1930))

// this should be 1900
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1830, -1, 1900, 1845))
```

Comment: there are no arrays in your code

Comment: @juvian copy-paste error. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a different approach. It calculates the minutes from midnight for all three timestamps and then uses the difference between the `left` and `right` timestamp in relation to the `desired` timestamp to determine which is nearest.

I tested it with many timestamps. Also some odd ones. Seems to work fine so far for all.

Hope this helps.

```js
const minutesFromMidnight = (t) => {
  const frac = t / 100;
  const hours = Math.trunc(frac);
  const mins = (frac - hours) * 100;
  const minsOfDay = (hours * 60) + mins;

  var minutesDist = 0;
  if (minsOfDay >= 720)
    minutesDist = minsOfDay - 1440;
  else
    minutesDist = minsOfDay;

  return minutesDist;
};

const getNearestToDesiredTime = (left, middle, right, desiredTime) => {
  if (middle !== -1) {
    return middle;
  } else if (left === -1 && right === -1) {
    return null;
  }

  const desiredDist = minutesFromMidnight(desiredTime);
  const leftDist = minutesFromMidnight(left);
  const rightDist = minutesFromMidnight(right);

  const leftDiff = Math.abs(leftDist - desiredDist);
  const rightDiff = Math.abs(rightDist - desiredDist);

  const leftIsCloser = leftDiff < rightDiff;

  return leftIsCloser ? left : right;
};

// this should be 1830
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1830, -1, 1945, 1845) + ' = 1830');

// this should be 1945
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1830, -1, 1945, 1930) + ' = 1945');

// this should be 1900
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1830, -1, 1900, 1845) + ' = 1900');

// this should be 1800
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1800, -1, 1900, 1745) + ' = 1800');

// this should be 1900
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(130, -1, 1900, 1600) + ' = 1900');

// this should be 130
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(1900, -1, 130, 2300) + ' = 130');

// this should be 2315
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(130, -1, 2315, 0) + ' = 2315');

// this should be 130
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime(130, -1, 2315, 100) + ' = 130');
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed it slightly to handle an array of times to be more generic. We keep track of the best difference and then return the time that made it

```js
// this should be 1900
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime([1830, 1900, 1945], 1900))

// this should be 1915
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime([1830, 1915, 1945], 1900))

// this should be 1830
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime([1830, 1945], 1845))

// this should be 1945
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime([1830, 1945], 1930))

// this should be 1900
console.log(getNearestToDesiredTime([1830, 1900], 1845))

function timeDiffInMinutes (t1, t2) {
  const t1Mins = Math.floor(t1 / 100) * 60 + t1 % 100;
  const t2Mins = Math.floor(t2 / 100) * 60 + t2 % 100;
  return t2Mins - t1Mins;
};


function getNearestToDesiredTime (times, target) {
  var best = Infinity;
  var bestIndex = -1;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      var difference = Math.abs(timeDiffInMinutes(times[i], target));
      if (difference <= best) {
          best = difference;
          bestIndex = i;
      }
  }
  return times[bestIndex];
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong if the second result should be `1915`. It is `1830` in your output. Isn't it?

Comment: @MarioWerner had assumed timeDiffInMinutes was correct, seems it was not. Fixed, thanks for noticing

Comment: Ok, but you run into the same problems as me, when I was experimenting with this `timeDiffInMinutes` function, when you compare odd times. For instance `getNearestToDesiredTime([130, 2300], 10)`, which would be `00:10` as target. It is 70 minutes to `23:00`, but 80 minutes to `1:30`, but it still shows `130` as nearest. It only works like this: `getNearestToDesiredTime([2530, 2300], 2410)`, but thats not only weird but wrong time notation. :D